# Maximize the function on a circle.

Tags: geometry, analysis, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, implicit-differentiation

let $f(x,y,z)=\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2},a>b>c>0$, what is the maximum of $f(x,y,z)$ under the restriction $x^2+y^2+z^2=1,x\cos\alpha +y\cos\beta+z\cos\gamma=0,\cos^2\alpha+\cos^2\beta+\cos^2\gamma=1?$

I noticed that the valid $(x,y,z)$ is on a circle where the normal vector of the surface of the circle is $(\cos\alpha,\cos\beta,\cos\gamma)$, but I don't know how to do then.

Another method I've tried is the Lagrange Multiplier method, but I still don't work it out.

I'll be grateful if there's any help :) .

Comment: Use a numercal global optimization solver. The problem only has 3 variables, so hopefully not too difficult.

Comment: You say that you tried Lagrange multipliers, “but I still don’t work it out.” Show your work! Perhaps you’re on the right track and are just getting stuck somewhere. If you show us what you’ve done so far, someone might be able to get you unstuck. The simplest approach, I think, would be to parameterize the circle and reduce this to s single-variable optimization problem.

Comment: Note that since the equation of the cutting plane is generic, you’ll need to do some case analysis to come up with a solution via parameterization.

Comment: Another possible approach is to restrict the quadratic form $f$ to the cutting plane and do a principal direction analysis on it, i.e., find an orthogonal diagonalization for it. This will require some case analysis, too, I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=\cos\alpha$, $v=\cos\beta$, and $w=\cos\gamma$. Then the Lagrange multiplier system of equations is

$$
\begin{align}
2x/a^2 - 2\lambda_1 x - \lambda_2 u &= 0 \nonumber \\
2y/b^2 - 2\lambda_1 y - \lambda_2 v &= 0 \nonumber \\
2z/c^2 - 2\lambda_1 z - \lambda_2 w &= 0 \nonumber \\
x^2+y^2+z^2-1 &= 0 \nonumber \\
xu + yv + zw &= 0. 
\end{align}
$$

The equation
$$
\begin{align}
  \lambda_1^2 &- \left[ u^2(1/b^2+1/c^2) + v^2(1/a^2+1/c^2) + w^2(1/a^2+1/b^2)\right]\lambda_1  \nonumber \\
   &+ (u^2/(b^2 c^2) + v^2/(a^2 c^2) + w^2/(a^2 b^2)) \nonumber \\
   &= 0
\end{align}
$$
follows from the previous system of equations.  The maximum and minimum values of $f$ are the maximum and minimum solutions for $\lambda_1$ in this quadratic equation.  I numerically verified this, but did not prove it algebraically.